# Firefox input email fills the next input text

Tags: angularjs, html, firefox

I have a form in with name, surname, email and date of birth
The mail is a "pre-compiled" field but in firefox (ONLY in firefox) I see the email also in the date of birth 
This is the code:

```
    <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group" data-ng-class="{'has-error': nameErrInvalid}">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="name"  placeholder="{{langfile[lang]['name_user']}}"  data-ng-required="true"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group" data-ng-class="{'has-error': surnameErrInvalid}">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="surname"  placeholder="{{langfile[lang]['surname_user']}}" data-ng-required="true"/>
            </div>
        </div>              
        <div class="col-sm-6"><!-- MAIL -->
            <div class="form-group" data-ng-class="{'has-error': emailErrInvalid}"><!--placeholder="Email" data-ng-required="true"-->
                <input type="email" class="form-control" data-ng-model="email" data-ng-disabled="emailDisabled"/>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6"><!-- DATA -->
            <div class="form-group" data-ng-class="{'has-error': dtErrInvalid}">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="date"  placeholder="{{langfile[lang]['wizarddateholder']}}" data-ng-required="true"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[firefox behaviour NOT OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdikD.jpg)

[image]

[chrome behaviour OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT0rE.jpg)

[image]

Comment: What does "pre-compiled" mean?

Comment: Is it because of autocomplete? Try adding `autocomplete="off"` to the date input field.

Comment: never every use autocomplete="off, it makes users angry. Also try to open page in new tab, doing refresh, browser auto fills fields, if it was filled before.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I tried but autocomplete="off" doesn't work...any other idea?